# Error: The method 'MaterialStatePropertyAll' isn't defined for the class 'DataTable2'

Tags: flutter

i use data_table_2: ^2.3.8

but im getting the error while running causing the app to be stopped

- 'DataTable2' is from 'package:data_table_2/src/data_table_2.dart' ('../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/data_table_2-2.3.8/lib/src/data_table_2.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MaterialStatePropertyAll'.
  ? MaterialStatePropertyAll(fixedColumnsColor)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/data_table_2-2.3.8/lib/src/data_table_2.dart:616:31: Error: The method 'MaterialStatePropertyAll' isn't defined for the class 'DataTable2'.
- 'DataTable2' is from 'package:data_table_2/src/data_table_2.dart' ('../../../AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/data_table_2-2.3.8/lib/src/data_table_2.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MaterialStatePropertyAll'.
  ? MaterialStatePropertyAll(fixedCornerColor)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

i tried to set fixedCornerColor and fixedColumnColors and the error still to be appeared!
anyone can help me fix this

my code is very normal :(

```
StreamBuilder(
                            stream: 
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').where('userID' ,isEqualTo: user.userID!)
                            .where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'completed')
                            .snapshots().map(Database().ordersListFromSnapshot ),
                            builder: (context, snapshot){
                              if(snapshot.hasData == false){
                                return Container(
                                  
                                );
                              }else{
                                List<Order> orderDoc = snapshot.data as List<Order>;
                                return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: 
                              DataTable2(
                                fixedColumnsColor: Colors.red,
                                //  dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.amber),
                                 fixedCornerColor: Colors.amber,
                                  columnSpacing: defaultPadding,
                                  minWidth: 750,
                                  horizontalMargin: 0,
                                  columns: [
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        "ID",
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        "Service",
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  rows: orderDoc
                                      .map((item) => DataRow(
                                            cells: [
                                              DataCell(Center(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                item.orderID!,
                                              )),
                                              onTap:() => _showOrderDetails(context,item)),
                                                      DataCell(StreamBuilder(
                                                          stream: FirebaseFirestore
                                                              .instance
                                                              .collection(
                                                                  'serviceFacility')
                                                              .doc(item
                                                                  .serviceFacilityID)
                                                              .snapshots(),
                                                          builder: (context,
                                                              snapshot) {
                                                            if (snapshot
                                                                    .hasData ==
                                                                false) {
                                                              return Container();
                                                            } else {
                                                              var servicefacilitydoc =
                                                                  snapshot.data
                                                                      as DocumentSnapshot;
                                                              return Center(
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                    servicefacilitydoc[
                                                                        'serviceFacilityName']),
                                                              );
                                                            }
                                                          })),
                                                      DataCell(StreamBuilder(
                                                          stream:
                                                              FirebaseFirestore
                                                                  .instance
                                                                  .collection(
                                                                      'payment')
                                                                  .doc(item
                                                                      .paymentID)
                                                                  .snapshots(),
                                                          builder: (context,
                                                              snapshot) {
                                                            if (snapshot
                                                                    .hasData ==
                                                                false) {
                                                              return Container();
                                                            } else {
                                                              var paymentdoc =
                                                                  snapshot.data
                                                                      as DocumentSnapshot;
                                                              return Center(
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                    '\$ ' +
                                                                        paymentdoc[
                                                                                'totalPayment']
                                                                            .toString(),
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: Colors
                                                                            .blue,
                                                                        fontWeight:
                                                                            FontWeight
                                                                                .bold)),
                                                              );
                                                            }
                                                          })),
                                                      DataCell(Center(
                                                          child:
                                                              ProviderRatingBar()
                                              ))
                                            ],
                                          ))
                                      .toList()),
                            ),
                          );
                              }
                            }
                          ),
```

Comment: are you using latest version of flutter?

Comment: i use Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (4 months ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2

Comment: Can you try upgrading

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the `data_table_2.dart` file. I guess they authors have not made an update to be compatible with flutter 3 yet. You can use this [file](https://gist.github.com/photizzo/4db3fd940c3f1f0961f856186d62ae8e) to replace `data_table_2.dart`